# Missing Maven Dependency and can not import class

Tags: java, apache, maven, project

I have created a new maven project by choosing `org.apache.maven.archtypes maven.archtype.webapp`.

I perform the below commands:

- right click pom > maven clean
- right click pom > maven install.
- check maven user setting file
- right click on project > maven update.

but maven dependency library is not added into libraries folder although a build success message has been output.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
<p> 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] Total time: 2.248 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-07T09:40:57+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
```

Here's my pom file, e.g dependency mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache. rg/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven.test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>maven.test Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here's my library screenshot without maven dependency

[image: library without maven dependency]

Answer (score 1):

As Amer mentioned , do a maven update for your project, if it doest work the try with different network(either use mobile phone network or home network) to update project then 
 do a eclipse clean(not maven clean) for that project then do a 
 `maven install`.
 sometimes network block the jar file to download

Answer (score 0):

right click on the project -> maven -> update project

Comment: I did but it is not work. All do this I perfom this instructions, 
* pom right click maven clean
* pom right click maven install.
* I checked maven user setting file
* project right click maven update.

Answer (score 0):

I saw screen shot you attached but there is not any folder called "Maven Dependencies". So please try one option it may solve your problem...right click on project -> configure -> convert to maven.

Answer (score 0):

go to the source folder of the project using cmd and 
run maven command:
mvn clean install (**this command won't work unless you specified path to maven/bin folder in path of system variables**)
be sure you're not beyond the proxy, if you are, then you should configure maven to work with it. Link to [how to configure a proxy in maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)